# Show content outside border with AspectFit in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to show content outside of the border of the scene when I use `.AspectFit` scale mode for the devices that don't match the aspect ratio of my scene. My scene is set up for iPhone 5 & 6 aspect ratio (1080 x 1920) and has some test nodes outside the area defined by the yellow border line:

[image]

The thick red lines around the white screen are just outside the border and should not be visible unless the content is letterboxed.

This is the code in my view controller that presents the scene:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"MainMenu") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

When I run it in iPhone 6s simulator I see the expected result, which is just the squares in the corners. However, when I run it in the 4s simulator, instead of the red bars on the right and left, I see black bars:

[image]

How can I tell the view controller / application to use the scene content instead of black emptiness to fill in extra space when the scene is resized to fit on the screen?

Comment: You may be looking for `.AspectFill`, however, I'm not sure if that will mess up your content...

Comment: `.AspectFill` will crop some of the scene - instead, I would like the scene to show the content that's placed outside of the borders - this way I can make sure that all elements of the UI are visible, and that there is enough content to fill the screen if the aspect ratio doesn't match.

Comment: I generally use .ResizeFill and make UI (as well as spriteNodes) sized based on the bounds of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and came up with something "hacky" that works. Keep using .aspectFit and dynamically adjust the aspect of your content to match the screen.

This code assumes you are using the default 0.5, 0.5 anchor point in the .sks file and you will need to set originalSize to what you were using when you designed the scene.

Anyone using this would do well to add some error checking to it and/or optimise it so it's not continuously running on every frame.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // hacky resize
    do {
        let originalSize = CGSize(720, 1140)
        let winSize = self.view!.frame.size
        let originalAspect = originalSize.width/originalSize.height
        let winAspect = winSize.width/winSize.height
        var newSize = originalSize; do {
            if winAspect > originalAspect {
                newSize.width = originalSize.height * winAspect
            } else if winAspect < originalAspect {
                newSize.height = originalSize.width / winAspect
            }
        }
        self.size = newSize
        self.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    }
}
```